# Rad dad radish adventures await

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Please help me figure out the meaning of the following sentence (used as a title) form the description of the app "Dadish 2":

> Rad dad radish adventures await

I know that the phrase "rad dad" means "excellent dad". However, I am confused by the words "raish adventures await." Maybe there is something wrong with the sentence structure here.

Here is a description of the app from Google Play:

*He’s a dad, and a radish, and he’s back in his biggest adventure yet! After an impromptu “Bring Your Kids To Work Day” goes awry, Dadish sets off to find his missing children. Along the way he’ll wade through swamps, ride rockets, climb a big tree, and even visit outer space! Help reunite Dadish with his missing kids in this charming and challenging platforming adventure.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a play on words.

First of all, "rad" is short for "radical," which is slang for "cool" or "hip." Adding the suffix "-ish" to something means that what it is added to is only somewhat but not exactly, so "rad" + "-ish" would mean "somewhat rad but not exactly rad" (i.e., It's kind of "rad" but falls short of actually being "rad.").

Second of all, a "radish" happens to be the name for a type of root vegetable.

The play on words is the double meaning of the adventure with dad being somewhat "rad" and dad being an actual "radish," the root vegetable. That alone is a humorous proposition, dad being a radish, but it becomes more humorous since it's a contradiction as radishes are *not* rad. Vegetables in general don't rise to the level of being considered cool or hip.

**The problem** with this particular play on words, however, is if you actually add the suffix "-ish" to "rad" to form a single, unhyphenated word, English orthography requires adding a second D, like is done to turn "bad" into "[baddish](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/baddish)," so an unhyphenated word formed out of "rad" and adding the suffix "-ish" to mean *somewhat rad* wouldn't be "radish," like how the vegetable is spelled, but would be "raddish," not like how the vegetable is spelled. So while this particular play on words works orally, it doesn't work in writing.

Answer (score 4):

It's an app. Grammar and vocabulary may be stretched.

I haven't looked, but I suspect the dad character is actually a radish, so of course he will have radish adventures.

Another alternative is that "radish" is "rad-ish", so adventures that are somewhat rad, so somewhat excellent.

Or both.

Comment: Yep, and it is soooo bad. And I don't mean good. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's meant to be hip and funny. *Rad dad* means *cool dad*. *Radish adventures* means what kind of adventures the player will have. Because the character is a radish (the vegetable), of course, he or she will have radish adventures. :) Also *radish* humorously sounds like someone was saying *rad-ish* (which means "rad...sort of", because of the "-ish"). Of course, that's slang and humorous, not a real definition.

The whole sentence describes what kind of adventures lie in store for the player "rad dad radish adventures".